# Генераторы в PHP - как это реализовать?

Tags: php, функции

1 Создать анонимную функцию и поместить её в переменную. Функция должна принимать массив и возвращать среднее значение всех элементов.

2 Создать функцию-генератор, принимающую двумерный массив и функцию. Эта функция на каждой итерации должна возвращать среднее значение текущего массива.

3 Создать двумерный массив из чисел.

4 С помощью foreach вывести все средние значения элементов двумерного массива.

p.s. у меня есть только представление  как реализовать 3 и 4 п, но это, видимо, не совсем верно, благодарю за помощь и критику)

```
$array = array(array(11,12,13, ..
$m = 0; 
$c = 0; 
foreach ($array as $e) { 
    $c += count($e); 
    $m += array_sum($e); 
} 
$m /= $c; 
echo "result: $m\n";
```

Comment: Продемонстрируйте наглядно первый пункт!

Comment: @misdeed eto PHP, detka!

Comment: @Manitikyl, деткой будешь называть свою девочку, или маму.

Comment: @misdeed хорошо, не заплачь тока

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
$ANONYMOUS = function ($ARRAY) {
    return array_sum($ARRAY)/count($ARRAY);
}
$INPUT = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
var_dump($ANONYMOUS($INPUT));
```

2)

```
function myGenerator($ARRAY, $FUNC) {
    foreach($ARRAY as $value) {
        yield $FUNC($value);
    }
}

$MAS = array(
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(4, 5, 6)
    );

foreach(myGenerator($MAS, function($ARRAY) { return array_sum($ARRAY)/count($ARRAY); }) as $value) {
 var_dump($value);
}
```

3)

```
$ARRAY = array(
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(4, 5, 6),
    array(7, 8, 9)
    );
```

4)

```
$ARRAY = array(
    array(1, 2, 3),
    array(4, 5, 6),
    array(7, 8, 9)
    );

foreach ($ARRAY as $value) {
    var_dump(array_sum($value)/count($value));
}
```

Comment: Очень хорошо, я имел ввиду, что-бы автор пораскинул мозгами немножко, а не ждал готового решения.

Answer (score 0):

Тут всё намного проще и понятнее. И не нужно воду мутить и что-то изобретать с нуля до гуру.

```
<?php

$anonim = function ($arr) {
    $sumAll = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $value) :
        $sumAll += $value;
    endforeach;
    return $sumAll / count($arr);
};

function MyGeneration($arr, $callback)
{
    $sumAll = 0;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($arr as $value) :
        foreach ($value as $v) :
            $sumAll += $v;
        endforeach;
        $i += count($value);
        yield $callback($value);
    endforeach;
    yield $sumAll / $i;
}

$twoArray = [
    [1, 2, 5, 4, 7],
    [3, 5, 1, 4, 7],
    [9, 8, 5, 0, 2]
];

foreach (MyGeneration($twoArray, $anonim) as $item) {
    echo $item;
    echo '<br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]